# map passed to empty Values variable by --set with helm --upgrade will be ignored

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am currently trying to pass a map via `helm upgrade --set mymap.value=xyz ...` to an empty value variable as following:

Values file:

```
(...)
myMap:
```

Executing the `helm upgrade` command is successful but states the following error: `warning: skipped value for myMap: Not a table.`

If I fill the `Values` file with a dummy map like

```
(...)
myMap:
   dummy:
```

then it is working and overwrites the whole map, deleting the existing `dummy` node.

This behavior cost me quite some time not realizing, that an empty list will be accepted but doing exactly the same with an empty map will not. I therefore just wanted to ask if this behavior is intended or if this is a bug that should be adressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As json is always valid yaml, it is possible to use `map: {}`, `array: []` for empty typed values.